# Bootstrap 4: selectpicker 1.13 doesn't properly fit selected option's content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

The problem is simply stylistic so far: the select itself doesn't fit the size of the selected option. It appears way too low and overflows the container. Plus the caret shows in the top right corner, not where it should be (in the middle right). Looks like this:

[image]

With following code:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-style='btn-primary'>
    <option value="value">I'm a sad and a little bit too long option</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, there are no problems with displaying the select dropdown itself, it's just that the button (the initial field with the currently selected value) appears all messed up for some reason. I suspect that might be a problem with the plugin itself, as I'm barely applying any related styles that might interfere. I'd like to receive an advise how I could get this to work properly, because I really like the plugin and wouldn't like to have to write all the functionality myself. I'm just not that good with css and understanding it's structures. I've had a look at the source html that the plugin is generating and it simply appears that the parent container (`div.filter-option`) misses some of the properties needed to tell it where to position the content (the text-containing element `div.filter-option-inner`) and how to handle it.

Source of the plugin (meant to be an officially compatible with Bootstrap 4 version of the Bootstrap Select plugin): https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.13.0
My version of Bootstrap is the default built in with Laravel 5.6 Bootstrap 4.0.
Any help/advise/analysis of the issue is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**
Very strange... The following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
<option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
<option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
<option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

provides a great result when displayed in a brand new pure jsfiddle, but pasted in a custom local (and online) `.html` file, it still displays messy. I'm really clueless as of why this might be happening!

Comment: why don't you apply style on the selectors and increase it's width...

Comment: Tried that, it worked. But I doubt this to be the default wanted brhaviour of the plugin. Plus it only solves the width problem. All the other messy layout persists. So I thought there was another major cause of that behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a really tough time figuring this out, I've come up with the actual cause of this behavior laying really deep underneath what appeared to be problematic. * drums * 
The problem was that the `<!DOCTYPE html>` was not being sent to the browser as the first thing in my html page's response. So actually that was causing the exceptual behavior of the plugin (apparently, that matter didn't affect ANYTHING else on my whole page until that point). 
What was causing that mistake though was the really funny part about it all. I'm using laravel to manage my views and was using a complex set of sections and stacks to load resources and content optimally. The whole problem came from the fact that in this one particular little piece of html code I was sending back to the browser, I had forgotten a small bit of `<style>` in a single tag at the very bottom of my `.blade.php` file, that was for some reason left after the `@endsection` directive. So basically laravel decided, that it should take precedence upon what was in the section tag and sent it first to my home view (which resultet in it rendering on top of the whole document rendered by the browser). Shoosh, that was tough. Thanks for the replies and the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to drop down size equal to select then you can use this CSS.

```
.bootstrap-select {
  position: relative !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0 !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
  white-space: initial !important; 
}
```

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```css
.bootstrap-select {
  position: relative !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0 !important;
  transform: translate3d(0, 37px, 0px) !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
  white-space: initial !important; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but these styles are already being set by the plugin, therefore they don't affect anything as of right now. I suspect that to be a plugin-source related issue though... or some kind of outer interference, but I've surely sorted that out...

Comment: but you can override it using `!important`

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I was saying was that those attributes were already being set with the same values, but yet the layout did not work properly. As I'm testing right now, it still doesn't appear right even with the sources provided by you. (Pasted the whole thing in a brand new `.html` file, it still appears wrongly. That's darn strange...

Comment: Maybe it's chache issue copy this snippet code make new file and check it.

Comment: I've figured it out, take a look at my own answer